# AMTU (Amazon Transport Utility) crashing and service not running

Tags: java, amazon-mws

Having a problem running AMTU on a windows 7 Pro Machine.

It runs fine when it opens but it crashes after running a few days.

Here is the Crash Report.

> 2013-09-14 09:48:19,482 [pool-3-thread-3] com.amazon.merchants.services.RetrieverService - Unable to retrieve unacknowledged report information - MWS Request ID unknown
>   2013-09-14 09:48:19,482 [pool-3-thread-3] com.amazon.merchants.services.RetrieverService - MWS responded with an error: Internal Error
>   com.amazonaws.mws.MarketplaceWebServiceException: Internal Error
>       at com.amazonaws.mws.MarketplaceWebServiceClient.processErrors(MarketplaceWebServiceClient.java:2342)
>       at com.amazonaws.mws.MarketplaceWebServiceClient.invoke(MarketplaceWebServiceClient.java:2231)
>       at com.amazonaws.mws.MarketplaceWebServiceClient.invoke(MarketplaceWebServiceClient.java:2011)
>       at com.amazonaws.mws.MarketplaceWebServiceClient.getReportList(MarketplaceWebServiceClient.java:1206)
>       at com.amazon.merchants.services.RetrieverService.processReportCheck(RetrieverService.java:94)
>       at com.amazon.merchants.services.RetrieverService.run(RetrieverService.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I also cannot start the Windows Service called AMTU. Get the following Error:

> The AMTU service on local computer has started and then stopped

I am suspecting its a Java version issue.

In the AMTU documentation it says "requires Java version 1.6.0 or later (listed as JDK/JRE - 6)" and links to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html. The link has many download links, but nothing listed "JDK/JRE - 6".

AMTU documentation: https://d28hcfptedr5ia.cloudfront.net/ug/AMTU_2.2_UserGuide.pdf

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read this crash report, AMTU got an unexpected result from the MWS servers:

```
MWS responded with an error: Internal Error
```

It seems the error handling in AMTU is not good enough to gracefully handle a HTTP status 500, and there is not a lot you can do about this. You could put a HTTP proxy in between and catch a HTTP 500 on the line before it gets to the AMTU, replacing it with something that AMTU handles more gracefully (e.g. an empty XML result or a time out). It would be preferrable though that Amazon doesn't send those errors back, after all, a 500 is an error on *their* side of things.

I seriously doubt the Java version has anything to do with this, but just in case: You can still download JRE6 even though it is end-of-life:

[Java 6 downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html)

Please note that the true name of JRE6 is "Java SE runtime environment" and JDK6 is called "Java SE development kit". At the time of writing, the most current version is "update 45". You may need to uninstall Java 7 to make sure the AMTU actually uses the version you want it to. Please also note that since AMTU is a 32bit process, you will need the 32bit JRE even if it is run on a 64bit windows.

Comment: Thank You for your response. For now I have a scheduled task to start the program in case it errord out.